# modal's internal content does not appear in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a modal for a canvas in an asp.net core mvc project using Visual Studio 2019.
I did a proof of concept in a separate project using Vs Code which worked well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="botaoModal">Teste Modal</button>

    <style>
        .modal-container{
            /* Vai fazer o moda ocupar 100% da largura da tela */
            width: 100vw; 
            /* Vai fazer o moda ocupar 100% da altura da tela */
            height: 100vh;
            /* Background do modal */
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
            /* Posição do modal */
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 2000;
            display: none;
            /* Centraliza o conteúdo do container no centro */
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .modal-container.mostrar{
            display: flex;
        }

        @keyframes modal {
            form{
                opacity: 0;
                transform: translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
            }
            to{
                opacity: 1;
                transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        .mostrar .modal{
            animation: modal .3s;
        }

        .modal{
            background: white;
            width: 85vw;
            height: 80vh;
            min-width: 300px;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 10px solid #5F9EA0;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            align-items: center;
            position: relative;
        }

        .fechar{
            position: absolute;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            top: -30px;
            right: -30px;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 4px solid white;
            background: #5F9EA0;
            color: white;
            font-family: serif, Arial;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
        }

        .center{
            text-align: center;
            top: 0px;
        }

        .right {
            float: right;
            height: 65vh; 
            border: 3px solid #73AD21;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        .left {
            float: left;
            /* width: 60vw;*/
            height: 65vh; 
            border: 3px solid #73AD21;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .container{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns:70% 30%;
            justify-content: stretch;
        }

        .container-lista{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns:50% 50%;
            justify-content: stretch;
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .scrool{
            overflow:auto;
        }

        .container-video{
            position: -ms-page;
            width: 56vw;
            height: 63vh;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .container-img{
            padding: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            width: 130px;
            height: 100px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>


    <div id="modal-promocao" class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal">
            <button id="botaoFechar" class="fechar">X</button>
            <h3 class="center">Nome da playlist</h3>
            <div id="videos" class="container">
                <div id="container_video" class="left" style="background: aqua;">
                    <iframe class="container-video" id="video-player"
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="right scrool container-lista" style="background: aqua;">
                    <img id="2NWeucMKrLI" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2NWeucMKrLI/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>
                    <img id="3DeLiClDd04" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3DeLiClDd04/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>

                    <img id="2NWeucMKrLI" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2NWeucMKrLI/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>
                    <img id="3DeLiClDd04" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3DeLiClDd04/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>

                    <img id="2NWeucMKrLI" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2NWeucMKrLI/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>
                    <img id="3DeLiClDd04" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3DeLiClDd04/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>

                    <img id="2NWeucMKrLI" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2NWeucMKrLI/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>
                    <img id="3DeLiClDd04" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3DeLiClDd04/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>

                    <img id="2NWeucMKrLI" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2NWeucMKrLI/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>
                    <img id="3DeLiClDd04" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3DeLiClDd04/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function iniciaModal(modalID){
            var modal = document.getElementById(modalID);
            modal.classList.add('mostrar');

            modal.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                if(e.target.id == modalID || e.target.id == 'botaoFechar'){
                    modal.classList.remove('mostrar');
                }
            });
        }

        var botaoAbrir = document.getElementById('botaoModal');
        botaoAbrir.addEventListener('click', function(){
            iniciaModal('modal-promocao');
        });

        function VideoSelecionado(id){
            var player = document.getElementById('video-player');
            player.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, when I went to pass the solution to my project, the modal is being shown, but it doesn't show the internal content, just the container, which is that gray part of the background that covers the entire screen. I ran some tests here, changed some things, but I still haven't come to a conclusion about what might be going on.

The modal's css code is in the modalPlaylistSearch.css file that was imported into the _Layout.cshtml file.

```css
/*BLOCO DE CSS DO MODAL DA TELA DE LISTA DE PLAYLIST*/

.modal-container {
    /* Vai fazer o moda ocupar 100% da largura da tela */
    width: 100vw;
    /* Vai fazer o moda ocupar 100% da altura da tela */
    height: 100vh;
    /* Background do modal */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    /* Posição do modal */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2000;
    display: none;
    /* Centraliza o conteúdo do container no centro */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

    .modal-container.mostrar {
        display: flex;
    }

@keyframes modal {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, -60px, 0);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

.mostrar .modal {
    animation: modal .3s;
}

.modal {
    background: white;
    width: 85vw;
    height: 80vh;
    min-width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 10px solid #5F9EA0;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.fechar {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    top: -30px;
    right: -30px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid white;
    background: #5F9EA0;
    color: white;
    font-family: serif, Arial;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
    top: 0px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    height: 65vh;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    /* width: 60vw;*/
    height: 65vh;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
    justify-content: stretch;
}

.container-lista {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    justify-content: stretch;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.scrool {
    overflow: auto;
}

.container-video {
    position: -ms-page;
    width: 56vw;
    height: 63vh;
    padding: 5px;
}

.container-img {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Likewise, the .js file that has the logic for the modal is in the modalPlaylistSearch.js file and has been imported into the page where the modal will be presented.

```js
function iniciaModal(modalID) {
    var modal = document.getElementById(modalID);
    modal.classList.add('mostrar');

    modal.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (e.target.id == modalID || e.target.id == 'botaoFechar') {
            modal.classList.remove('mostrar');
        }
    });
}

function abrirModal() {
    iniciaModal('modal-promocao');
}

function VideoSelecionado(id) {
    var player = document.getElementById('video-player');
    player.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + id;
}
```

This is the code for the page that has enable modal

```html
@model IEnumerable<ZonaLivre_WebApp.Dommain.Modelos.CommonSearch.PlayListItem>
@using Microsoft.JSInterop

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Playlist Search";
}

<body>
    <h1>Playlist Search</h1>
    <div>
        <form id="form" asp-action="PlaylistConsulta">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search">
            </div>
            <div id="root">
                <div id="left_side" class="form-group left_side">
                    <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" class="btn btn-danger button-tamanho-padrao">
                </div>
                <div id="btnplaylist" class="right_side hidden">
                    <input type="button" value="Playlist" id="Playlist" class="btn green-button button-tamanho-padrao" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />

    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <div class="o-card_container">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="o-card" id="@item.Id.PlaylistId">
                    <div class="o-card_header">
                        <!-- Imagem de fundo do cartão -->
                        <div class="o-card_headerHeroImg" data-image="@item.Snippet.Thumbnails.High.Url"></div>
                        <input id="@item.Id.PlaylistId" class="o-card_logo" type="checkbox" value="Selecionar" onclick="Guardar(id)" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- Sessão abaixo da foto com informações de texto do card -->
                    <div class="o-card_body">
                        <!-- TITULO DA PLAY LIST -->
                        <h2 class="o-card_title">@item.Snippet.Title</h2>
                        <!-- NOME DO CANAL -->
                        <h3 class="o-card_subTitle">@item.Snippet.ChannelTitle</h3>
                        <!-- DESCRIÇÃO DA PLAYLIST -->
                        <p class="o-card_paragraph">@item.Snippet.Description</p>
                    </div>


                    <!-- Botão Read More que abre texto sobre a personalidade -->
                    <div class="o-card_footer">
                        <a data-href="Albert_Einstein" class="a-readMore" data-modal="#first" onclick="abrirModal();">Read More <i class="icon-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <br>
        <div>
            <p>Faça uma pesquisa</p>
        </div>
    }

    <div id="modal-promocao" class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal">
            <button id="botaoFechar" class="fechar">X</button>
            <h3 class="center">Nome da playlist</h3>
            <div id="videos" class="container">
                <div id="container_video" class="left" style="background: aqua;">
                    <iframe class="container-video" id="video-player"
                            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="right scrool container-lista" style="background: aqua;">
                    <img id="2NWeucMKrLI" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2NWeucMKrLI/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>
                    <img id="3DeLiClDd04" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3DeLiClDd04/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>

                    <img id="2NWeucMKrLI" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2NWeucMKrLI/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>
                    <img id="3DeLiClDd04" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3DeLiClDd04/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>

                    <img id="2NWeucMKrLI" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2NWeucMKrLI/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>
                    <img id="3DeLiClDd04" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3DeLiClDd04/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>

                    <img id="2NWeucMKrLI" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2NWeucMKrLI/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>
                    <img id="3DeLiClDd04" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3DeLiClDd04/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>

                    <img id="2NWeucMKrLI" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2NWeucMKrLI/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>
                    <img id="3DeLiClDd04" class="container-img" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3DeLiClDd04/hqdefault.jpg" onclick="VideoSelecionado(id);"></img>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/js/modalPlaylistSearch.js" defer></script>

    <script>
        var listaDeIds = [];
        function Guardar(id)
        {
            var index = listaDeIds.indexOf(id);

            if (index > -1)
            {
                listaDeIds.splice(index, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                listaDeIds.push(id);
            }

            if (listaDeIds.length > 0)
            {
                document.getElementById('btnplaylist').style.display = 'flex';
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('btnplaylist').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }

        $('#Playlist').click(function () {
            var url = "/PlaylistSearch/PegarListaDeIds"
            var lista = listaDeIds;

            $.post(url, { pListaDeIds: lista }, function (data) {
                $("#msg").html(data);
            });

            var url = '@Url.Action("CreatePlaylist", "Playlist")';
            window.location.href = url.replace();
        });
    </script>
}
```